# Android studio git unexpected status r091

Tags: git, android-studio

I noticed very strange error (bug).

Someone in the team renamed or moved some files in the project (via Refactoring), commited and pushed them.
I pulled those changes from server, merge them (if needed).

But when I tried to commit merge above, got next error - "Commit failed, unexpected status r091" and two file names - old file name (before remove) and new one (after remove).

Answer (score 2):

I was investigating and found that when I'm trying to commit changes, both file names are present in commit.

Solution was simple - instead of pressing Git - commit directory I printed in Terminal:

```
git commit -m "Merge with renamed files
```

Voila! No error message anymore.

PS. Really strange and weird bug.

Comment: Same thing helped me when having `Unexpected status: R073`. Strange, but at least old school terminal method works. ;-)